# Using a mail rule/Applescript/Automator flow to download a PDF behind an HTML button

Tags: email, applescript, automator

I'm receiving BCC emails from a branded photo activation and tasked with automatically saving a copy of the photo included with each email.

The emails are HTML-coded and the link to the PDF I'm tasked with saving is attached to a button (i.e. "Click here to see your photo").

I've successfully created the following flow, but it won't download the PDF from the HTML email, it will only download if the PDF is linked in plain text. Any help would getting the raw email would be greatly appreciated...

1. Mail Rule to run AppleScript on all messages
2. Applescript code:

   ```
      property workFlowPath : quoted form of ("/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Applescript/WORKFLOWNAME.workflow")


   using terms from application "Mail"
       on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
           repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
       (*Get the email Subject *)
       set input_Argument to content of eachMessage
       (*Run subroutine for workflow *)
       my runAutomator(input_Argument)
     end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
   end using terms from

   (*Workflow  Subroutine *)
   on runAutomator(input_Argument)

   (*Path to workflow *)


   (*Setup and Run the unix command *)
   set command to "/usr/bin/automator   -i " & quoted form of    input_Argument & space & workFlowPath
   do shell script command
   end runAutomator
   ```
3. The workflow it triggers runs an automator flow that only saves files ending in ".pdf" to a designated folder

Comment: After plugging away at this, I'm able to extract the source, however it looks like the raw source Apple's mail program spits out breaks up the link i need...

Link example: <http://app.client.com/photo_output/photo_1982838287367.pdf>

What the source gives me: <http://http://app.client.com/photo_output/photo_1982838287367.p=df>

So when I run any URL extraction on it, it gives me up until the ".p"

Any ideas?

Comment: that first link sends me to some auto insurance quote site.

Comment: the links are dummy links. sorry

Comment: as a note, i've solved the problem by shortening the output URL. now mail doesn't insert a line break and all is well. answering the question though might still benefit some readers. i suspect there might be a way to search for the ".p=df" where "=" is the line break and simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the browser select the download button and then activate a left click. The only issue is that you would have to specify a specific part of the website.

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't work for this. I need to automate the process. The links come in via email and are in HTML. I've been able to extract the link, but they are too long and email adds a line break. How do I correct the line break?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the words copying down and go to a website called txtformat.com and replace &N with nothing. Then paste the result and return to the email to download.